# How to reference other elements using tailwindcss?

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

```
.post {
   @apply w-96 bg-zinc-950 text-white rounded-lg shadow-md max-w-md my-6
}

.post:hover {
    @apply cursor-pointer transition-all transform hover:scale-105 delay-300 shadow-lg bg-blue-500 text-white 
}

.post-image {
    @apply w-96 h-96 object-contain bg-zinc-900
}

.post-image:hover {
    @apply cursor-pointer transition-all transform hover:scale-105 delay-300 shadow-lg bg-blue-500
}
```

I have a basic card that swaps colors when you hover over it. How do I reference post-image to change its background color to blue in post:hover without creating a separate hover element in post-image:hover? Right now, if I hover the post only the card background changes. The image element background does not change until I hover my mouse over the post AND image at the same time.

Comment: I don't know how the HTML structure, but I'm assuming its's nested where the `.post-image` is the child of `.post`. So have you tried something like this: `.post:hover .post-image { @apply bg-blue-500; } `

Comment: this worked! thank you!